# Rails - Stylesheet require - choose specific stylesheets for each page

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently developing a rails app that will have a large amount of css files and many views.

The difficulty that I am coming across is the best way to structure my stylesheet asset pipeline.

Ideally I would have this set-up:

```
|-- app
|   |-- assets
|       |-- images
|       |-- javascripts
|       |-- stylesheets
|           |
|           |-- application.css
|           |
|           |-- layouts
|           |   |-- default_layout.css
|           |   |-- dashboard_layout.css
|           |   |-- landing_page_layout.css
|           |
|           |-- controllers
|           |   |-- users
|           |   |   |-- profile.css
|           |   |   |-- account_details.css
|           |   |-- products
|           |       |-- index.css
|           |       |-- purchase.css
|           |
|           |-- shared
|           |   |-- sidebar.css
|           |   |-- searchresults.css
|           |   |-- search filter.css
|           |
|           |-- lib
|           |   |-- files such as uisliders etc
|           |
|           |--unique_pages
|           |   |-- onetimepagedesign.css
|           |   |-- onetimepagedesign2.css
```

Where for any view only the css (and js) relating to it is used.

So if the user profile page is requested then only the css files which are needed:

```
stylesheets/controllers/user/profile.css    
stylesheets/layout/dashboard_layout.css    
stylesheets/shared/sidebar.css    
stylesheets/application.css    
stylesheets/lib (all files inside)
```

At the moment, since require _tree is in application every file is being condensed into application.css but this will eventually create a number of problems with different views interfering and the file getting too large.

is there a way to add stylesheet link tags or using directive and manifest so that this is accomplished?

Comment: Ideally, you should follow the Rails convention and not fight it. What you should do instead is make sure you have a base class at the top of each page. For instance, if you have a profile page, ensure that the top class is '.profile.' Then, in your CSS files, base all of your CSS off of that top class. It ensures that you won't have conflicting CSS throughout your pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use different `layout` and can load different `assets` on every `layout`.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "css_file_name" .... %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "js_file_name" ... %>
```

Then you can define your `controller` `actions` which `layout` should `render`, wish you can get an idea from here.

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.html {render :layout => 'your_layout_name'}
end
```